# Comparing two variable values in jquery but getting result value 0 always

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML CODE**

```
<div><input type="text" disabled value="<?php echo $res['pro_quantity']; ?>" id="available"></div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
function quantity_check()
{
  var avail = $('#available').val();
  var quant = $('#quantity').val();
  //alert(avail)
  if (quant<=avail){
     return true;
  }
  else
    $('#quantity').val(0);
  }
```

here is what when i enter any value in quantity field it changes value to 0.it seems t is not checking first condition.

Comment: you are comparing strings. what sort of values are being used?

Comment: integer values. but now it is workin by adding +$('#available').val();

Answer (score 1):

You are compare strings in your case.
Use:

```
var avail = +$('#available').val();
var quant = +$('#quantity').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert those two values into number/integer, as you are comparing strings:

```
 var avail = parseInt($('#available').val(),10);
 var quant = parseInt($('#quantity').val(),10);
```

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy FYI - modern browsers now default to 10.

Comment: @charlietfl Can you quote it in a document?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#ECMAScript_5_removes_octal_interpretation

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp    `As of ECMAScript 5, the default is the decimal radix (10).`

Comment: still doesn't mean it's safe to omit  it if supporting older browsers